# Change auto mount directory of SD card

Tags: linux, bash, mount, sd-card

I want to write a bash script to backup a certain directory, but only to a particular SD card. I want the script to have a way to check if this particular SD card is inserted. I run Lubuntu, which automatically mounts the SD card when it is inserted. How can I go about making sure that the auto mount directory is always called one name, and that only this one SD card will ever be mounted to it?

Cheers,
Ren.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I go about making sure that the auto mount directory is always called one name ?

The system will use the filesystem's label as mount point name if it finds one. You can use [gparted](http://gparted.org/) to set one if there's none currently (after unmounting it first).

Now some other device could also use that same name. To prevent that you can use the UUID returned by [blkid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/blkid.8.html) to uniquely identify your device. For example (replace sdb1 with your device):

```
$ sudo blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sdb1
6bf2435a-6afb-49d7-25a9-3577127a3bfb
```

Then store the value in your script and use it to check devices afterwards.